# Unexpected value '...' imported by the module '...'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular.

**Steps:**

1. Cloned this simple UI lib that demonstrates the current Angular package standards:  https://github.com/jasonaden/simple-ui-lib
2. Created a new test app with `ng new testApp`
3. `npm link` the `simple-ui-lib/dist`
4. `npm link simple-ui-lib` in the testApp
5. Imported the example module from simple-ui-lib into testApp:

In the app.module.ts file:

```
import { BoxModule } from 'simple-ui-lib';

...

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    BoxModule
  ]
})
```

Webpack compiles fine, but I get this error in the browser and nothing loads:

> compiler.es5.js:1540 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'BoxModule'
>   imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

**I've tried:**

- Clearing my npm cache
- Re-installing all node modules
- Forcing all Angular modules to be the same version in both projects
- Checked that all Angular modules are the same version in both projects
- Checked that the TypeScript version is the same in both projects
- Using other sample module packages instead of `simple-ui-lib`
- Created an entirely new project with the same setup
- Downgrading the `rollup` version used in `simple-ui-lib` to a build from January

If I console log the `BoxModule`, I can see the value exists and it seems to be registered as an @NgModule, so I'm confused about what this error is trying to tell me.

I've seen this error around in my searches, but it looks like they are almost always caused by a version mismatch between the library and the host application.  In my case, the versions are the same.

**Versions:**

- TypeScript: 2.2.0
- @angular/cli: 1.0.4
- @angular/common: 4.1.3

Any ideas?

*Update:*  Investigating more, looks like this is a problem with @angular/cli itself.  Opened a bug here:  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6429, but if you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: This may help: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/linked-library.md

Comment: i'm having the same issue with a ChartsModule from ng2-charts..  it's only an issue on aot though.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use es6 compiler instead of es5.
I encountered similar issue before and chaging the compilation mode solved the problem

I also recommand you To use the last angular cli version and upgrade to angular 5